# How to connect a curved line shape to other shapes using the Pen Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, pen-tool, raster

I'm trying to create a curved line with the pen tool, which I can do, but it automatically fills in the semicircle I'm trying to make. Sure, I can just set it to not fill, but when it comes times to rasterization, it fills in the semicircle automatically.

After that, it is rather hopeless I think. I tried setting Blend to Clear but then nothing will show.... **All I'm trying to do is connect a curved line shape to other shapes.**

I tried just making a path in pen tool and doing "combine other shapes" but that doesn't work for some reason? I am using CS6 here. How do I alleviate the problem of auto-fill after rasterization? I can use Magic Eraser tool I found out to delete the autofill after rasterization, but I'm wondering if there is a different way.

Comment: I tried my best to do as many weird things I could to replicate your description, but I couldn't. Could you please provide more information and maybe a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop does not support open vector paths.

Your issue is most likely due to an open path and upon output Photoshop fills the open path creating the semi-circle. You need to **draw closed shapes in Photoshop**, or stroke an open path and use pixels. There's no method I'm aware of to use open paths in Photoshop, everything **must** be closed.